# How to change Date format during imp

Tags: oracle, datetime, import

I am trying to import 1 file Oracle with Imp method. There is error with date format given in the script with default value

```
 DEFAULT 'Jan011753 12:00:00 AM'
```

Is there any way to change the Oracle date format during the import?

Comment: The problem is that 'Jan011753.......' is not a date, it is a string (varchar2). For that to be a date, it should be `DEFAULT to_date('Jan011753 12:00:00 AM', 'Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM')`. Alternatively, change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`: `ALTER SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM'`. That is, assuming the default is January 01, 1753 - is it?

Comment: I agree with mathguy that the implicit date format is a problem.  But I think you may need to run `ALTER SYSTEM ...` instead of `ALTER SESSION...`, and then change it back when the import is done.

Comment: jon Heller it is alter session itself :)

Comment: @mathguy  Ok thanks I do aware of it, my question is how to alter the date format before the imp command in CMD. I try to alter session in sql and run the imp in cmd, however its failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AFTER LOGON` changes date format of any user who log on. Better run

```
SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT="Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM" (Windows)
export NLS_DATE_FORMAT="Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM" (Linux)
```

In Windows it should be also possible to set it in your Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle home name}\NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, resp. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle home name}\NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

before you start `imp`, then the strange format is valid only for your session and you can revert it back under your control.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM';
```

or

```
DEFAULT to_date('Jan011753 12:00:00 AM', 'Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM');
```

> > The value Jan011753 is a string that's the problem

Comment: How to do the alter before i run imp in cmd?

Comment: can you please explain what you actually want ?

Comment: I think `alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ...` is not the best solution because the user may change it at any time. Better use `DEFAULT to_date('Jan011753 12:00:00 AM', 'Monddyyyy hh:mi:ss AM')`

Comment: i found the solution is 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_DATE_FORMAT
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
CALL DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('NLS_DATE_FORMAT','"MONDDYYYY HH12:MI:SS AM"')
/

the reason is imp is running using CMD not SQLPLUS , hence the alter session is not applicable

Comment: @TinyIss - Why is that the solution, and not adding TO_DATE to the string in the DEFAULT clause? No need for a trigger!

Comment: default to_date is better idea i think

Comment: @mathguy as its IMP method given by the Client, there is no way i can edit the script